# FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build when using getX?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a timerController:

```dart
class TimerController extends GetxController {
  int secondsRemaining = 5;

  late Timer timer;
  void startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      secondsRemaining--;
      update();
      // Check if the timer has reached 0
      if (secondsRemaining <= 0) {
        // Stop the timer when it reaches 0
        stopTimer();
      }
    });
  }

  void stopTimer() {
    timer.cancel();
  }
}
```

And I init the controller in **PageA**:

```dart
class _PageAState extends State<PageA> {
  TimerController timerController =
      Get.put(TimerController());
}
```

Then I push to **PageB**:

```dart
Get.to(() => PageB());
```

```dart
class _PageBState extends State<PageB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: GetBuilder<TimerController>(builder: (controller) {
                      if (controller.secondsRemaining == 0) {
                        //error here!
                        Get.back();
                      }
                      return Text('${controller.secondsRemaining}s',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right);
                    }),
  );
  }
}
```

It crashed when calling **Get.back()**, and the reason is **FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build**.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During build process it's not appropriate calling `setState()` which invoke the rebuild again. That cause the errore you are getting.

You can use a different approach to call `Get.back();` getting it out from the build method or if it's necessary to call it in that point you have to use something like this (code below) which allows you to register a Callable by `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` after the build process has finished.

```
typedef ActionAfterBuild = void Function();

class _PageBState extends State<PageB> {
  ActionAfterBuild? actionAfterBuild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GetBuilder<TimerController>(builder: (controller) {
        if (controller.secondsRemaining == 0) {
          //error here!
          actionAfterBuild = Get.back();
        }
        return Text('${controller.secondsRemaining}s', textAlign: TextAlign.right);
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted && actionAfterBuild != null) {
        actionAfterBuild!.call();
        actionAfterBuild = null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but here is an error: **Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.**

Comment: Ciao @magic_9527 you must change `typedef ActionAfterBuild = void Function();` in `typedef ActionAfterBuild = (TYPE_YOU_WANT_TO_HAVE) T Function();`

Comment: And @magic_9527 note that the `typedef's` declaration goes out of classes.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. **WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback** isn't called after **actionAfterBuild = Get.back()**.

Comment: I move **WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {}** to **error here**, it works!

Comment: Although I'm glad you've resolved your issue I want to say that putting listener of callbacks on build method isn't a good technique.  :)

Comment: Could u plz tell me what's the right way to deal with this? I use the state value, and I wanna do something when value changes.

Comment: build method is called every time a widget needs to be refreshed. Doing so you are going to register X times that happens. Callback registers have to be registered  once, so, the right place to do this is `onInitState` and/or on constructor (but here you have to be more precise, how and what you are making for)

Comment: But **WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback** isn't called when **controller.secondsRemaining == 0**.

Comment: `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` is a register manager for callbacks. All inside of that register is called when build is finished even you have declared the registering on constructor. What you have to do is that  when `controller.secondsRemaining == 0` declare a function which have to be called on end of frame, which is `actionAfterBuild = Get.back();`. on end of frame `actionAfterBuild` executes and at this point make itself to null. Every build you renew `actionAfterBuild` if  `controller.secondsRemaining == 0`